# Почему не работают параметры пользователя на RDP ферме

Tags: windows, администрирование, windows-server, rdp

Имеется Windows server 2012 R2. На ней стоит RDP ферма с пол сотней активных юзеров. В какой то из моментов перестали работать параметры(скриншот). В частности на вкладке (Сеансы - Завершение сеанса, Ограничение активного сеанса, и Ограничение бездействующего сеанса), а так же на вкладке (Среда - Запуск программы). После входа юзера, нужная программа не запускается, а просто разворачивается полноценный рабочий стол. В реестре ничего такого не менялось, в параметрах политики так же.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UDP: Уточню что это локальные пользователи. Но при этом если заходить при помощи пользователей домена с такими же указанными параметрами, то картина остаётся прежней.